# Regarding Trading view In-built indicator Custom Screener

Tags: pine-script, indicator

Recently I came across one beautiful trading view indicator that has made such a way that you can screen up to 100 scripts with own custom condition.

But there is one problem for me: I set my alert based on certain different pattern and made is as one pattern. Now I tried to put `screenerFunc()` as a pattern but it doesn't recognise and it's giving me the error

> Cannot destructure expression of type 'series[bool]'. Tuple expected.

I tried to workaround but my almost all possibilities giving different error each time. Only I am looking for in label stock name that found that pattern so I don't need to check all chart for that same.

Indicator link is https://www.tradingview.com/script/hDKwJ8yo-CustomScreener/.

This CustomScreener by TraderX_Unknown.

I know there may be a way I can screen my pattern in screenerfunction. If someone has an idea how to play with this code then please assist me to find out.

Answer (score 0):

The screener function's output from the linked script contain 2 values and should be declared using the `[]` brackets. Both values cannot be assigned to a single variable, as per your error:

```
// Screener Function
screenerFunc() => 
    rsi  = rsi(close, rsi_length) // Value
    cond = rsi > rsi_overbought     // Condition
    [rsi, cond]
```

As can be seen in the original script, the screenerFunc is passed to the security() function as 2 variables have been assigned for each ticker: rsi value and a boolean condition:

```
[value1, name1]   = security(s_1, timeframe.period, screenerFunc())
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @e2e4 .still unable to do it.i wanna apply this on following indicator   https://www.tradingview.com/script/laXINY3Q-CSPD/  But only on patternFound condition.so i am expecting result that  lable with stock in it that has that pattern found.even in bracket if i put patternFound but still confused what to write in value. once again thank you very much i hope we will find solution on it

Comment: Again i started from scratch but this time i am getting following error    Cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function.

Comment: how  to  convert mutable value of patternFound ??? Does anyone has idea about. it?

Comment: Have you found any solution?or its not possible.Please  let me know so i can mark as accept answer.appreciate your help.

Comment: security() function does not accept mutable variables, extract the value you wish to pass to the security function or rehash the method of the mutable variable calculations.